# Drag and drop onto SwapChainPanel in UWP app

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, winrt-xaml

We have a UWP application that uses a SwapChainPanel for rendering 2D content, we'd like to be able to drag and drop files on it.

**First approach:**

Firstly I just tried using the events on the SwapChainPanel itself, they never get called.

```
        <SwapChainPanel x:Name="swap" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="Swap_DragEnter" >

        </SwapChainPanel>
```

**Second approach:**

I then tried putting a transparent rectangle in the SwapChainPanel. The drag events do work now, but the SwapChainPanel now doesn't receive any pointer events at all.

```
        <SwapChainPanel x:Name="swap" >
            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="Swap_DragEnter"  />
        </SwapChainPanel>
```

**Third approach:**

It seems the SwapChainPanel doesn't work like a normal XAML control, so I assumed I'd have to handle the drag events in the c++ code that runs the panel. But there doesn't seem to be any way of doing this, there are only references to the basic pointer events.

```
    ...
    coreInput_ = renderPanel_.CreateCoreIndependentInputSource(deviceTypes);

    coreInput_.PointerPressed({this, &InputManagerImpl::onPointerPressed});
    coreInput_.PointerMoved({this, &InputManagerImpl::onPointerMoved});
    coreInput_.PointerReleased({this, &InputManagerImpl::onPointerReleased});
    coreInput_.PointerEntered({this, &InputManagerImpl::onPointerEntered});
    coreInput_.PointerExited({this, &InputManagerImpl::onPointerExited});
    coreInput_.PointerCaptureLost({this, &InputManagerImpl::onPointerCaptureLost});
    coreInput_.PointerWheelChanged({this, &InputManagerImpl::onPointerWheelChanged});
    ...
```

So now I'm not sure how I can peform drag/drop operations? Thanks!

Comment: I think you could place your `SwapChainPanel` inside a `Grid`, and put the drag and drop onto the grid. You might loose interaction with your render scene though. And, make sure, since it's transparent, it accepts user input.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, you are correct, putting it inside a grid does work.

Comment: I'll post it as answer then XD

Answer (score 0):

I think you could place your `SwapChainPanel` inside a `Grid`, and put the drag and drop onto the grid. You might loose interaction with your render scene though. And, make sure, since it's transparent, it accepts user input.

For example:

```
<!-- add attributes and drag and drop functionality on Grid -->
<Grid AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="Swap_DragEnter"> 
     <SwapChainPanel x:Name="swap">

     </SwapChainPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: SwapChainPanel is already a Grid, but you gotta put it inside another Grid to make it work properly, Microsoft are taking the wacky approach here I guess.